# Google GeoLocation API returns different results for the same wifi access point

Tags: google-geolocation

We are using Google's geolocation API to get the latlong for the wifi access points.  We are seeing inconsistent results.  Google's API returns different latlong on different boxes.  When I test on my development box, I get the latlong which points to a location in US.  When I test the same on the amazon ec2 box, I get the latlong which points to a location in Japan.  Has anybody else experienced the same with Google's GeoLocation API?
Below is the code and the response strings from both hosts.  JDK and JSON jar version is same on both the hosts.

```
public void testWifiIdMappingApi() {

    String apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

InputStream inputStream = null;
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
DataOutputStream wr = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(apiUrl);                  
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray wifiAry = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject wifiObj = new JSONObject();
    wifiObj.put("macAddress", "6c:f3:7f:4b:37:74");
    wifiObj.put("signalStrength", 60);
        wifiAry.add(wifiObj);
    wifiObj = new JSONObject();
    wifiObj.put("macAddress", "6c:f3:7f:4b:37:75");
    wifiObj.put("signalStrength", 60);
    wifiAry.add(wifiObj);
    obj.put("wifiAccessPoints", wifiAry);
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
    wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(obj.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    inputStream = null;
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        } else {
    inputStream = con.getErrorStream();
        }
    final char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    int read;
    do {
    read = r.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if (read > 0) {
        response.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    } while (read >= 0);
    System.out.println(new java.util.Date() + " - "
                + response.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
    if (inputStream != null)
        inputStream.close();
    if (wr != null)
        wr.close();
    if (con != null)
        con.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

}

**Input JSON String**

{"wifiAccessPoints":[{"signalStrength":60,"macAddress":"6c:f3:7f:4b:37:74"},
    {"signalStrength":60,"macAddress":"6c:f3:7f:4b:37:75"}]}

**Response on the amazon ec2 host**
{
    "location": {
        "lat": 40.603124,
        "lng": 140.463922
     },
     "accuracy": 122000.0
}

**Response on my development box (windows 7)**

{
    "location": {
        "lat": 37.593392,
        "lng": -122.04383
    },
    "accuracy": 22000.0
}

Comment: I think you should add the code you're using to query the Google's Geolocation API

Comment: I have added the code, input json string and the response strings from both hosts. please check.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass the `considerIp` field as False in your POST body. This would be what Google determines to be your location when the wifi routers aren't doing their job.